# How I could raise a footnote?

Tags: footnotes, raise

I try to use the `\footnote` command inside `\raisebox`. But then the text of the footnote disappears! Is there a simple way to appear the footnote back? Please, take this `XeLaTeX` MWE

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ Mapping=tex-tex]{Arial}
\begin{document}
Heavy\raisebox{1ex}{things are difficult to lift!\footnote{You are right!}}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You have to set it separately using `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` *outside* the `\raisebox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=15\baselineskip]{geometry}
\begin{document}
Heavy\raisebox{1ex}{things are difficult to lift!\footnotemark}\footnotetext{You are right!}
\end{document}
```